# Set a value on form submit if checkbox is checked in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form that creates a Post. A Post has a non-required field called school_id. On the Post form (to create a new Post) I have a checkbox. If that checkbox is checked, I want to set :school_id to equal the school_id that's also set to current_user (object created by Devise). How can I set the Post.school_id to equal current_user.school_id if the checkbox is checked?

The checkbox I have on the form is passing a :school_id of 1 and never changes. Is this because checkboxes can only accept boolean values of either 1 or 0? Here's what I have on the form so far:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, required: true %>

  <% if @school %>
     <%= f.label :school_id, "Set school",:class => "checkbox inline"  %>
     <%= f.check_box :school_id, :value => current_user.school.id %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Submit Post", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

post controller

```
def create
  @school = current_user.school
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  @post.school_id = current_user.school_id if @school && @post.use_school.present?     
  end
```

controller with the post form

```
def index
    @post = current_user.posts.build  
    @school = current_user.school
    @post.school_id = current_user.school_id if @school && @post.use_school.present?
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json
      format.js 
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from Simpleform! Simpleform forces checkbox input to be a boolean. You'll have the same problem with other syntaxes:

```
<%= f.input :school_id, :as => :boolean, :input_html => { :value => current_user.school.id } %>
```

To go deeper:

```
<%= f.check_box :school_id, :value => current_user.school.id %>
```

will generate something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post[school_id]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="post[school_id]" value="1">
```

Note: Simpleform automatically adds the first line (a good practice) to be sure that a value (0) is sent on submit when the input is unchecked. Otherwise, you may have issues on model update.

Your field is not a boolean, you shouldn't use a checkbox. Moreover, an user can edit the value of the checkbox (firebug & co) and that may lead to inconsistent datas or hack. So, with a checkbox you should check the `school_id` is correct in your controller.

I suggest this workarround:

app/views/posts/new.rb:

```
<% if @school %>
    <%= f.label :use_school, "Set school",:class => "checkbox inline"  %>
    <%= f.input :use_school, :as => :boolean %>
<% end %>
```

app/models/post.rb:

```
attr_accessor :use_school
```

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.school_id = current_user.school_id if @school && @post.use_school.present?
```

Note: the controller part may be done directly in your model with a `:before_save`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the detailed reply. That's a neat trick using the attr_accessor method. I really need to read up on that.

Comment: hmm...when I create a new post it seems to always set the boolean to true regardless of whether the checkbox is checked. Any ideas as to what's causing this?

Comment: Doh… Check in your rails logs which value is received.

Comment: Maybe try with this in the condition: !@post.use_school.to_i.zero?

Comment: It looks like use_school is passing in as 0 to the controller when I don't check it, but the school is still being set to the Post

Comment: I updated the question. I think the problem is the validation in the controller. I'm not using a post/new page for the post form. The form is rendered on a completely different controller and then the params are sent to the post controller for creation

Comment: If you have a "0" string, you need to cast with `to_i`, and then use `zero?` or `!!` (bang bang). Otherwise, add your controller code and I look it. :-)

Comment: OK, I think this works for real this time! Thanks again! Why wouldn't pass an integer to begin with? Wasn't it a boolean? I find that confusing

Comment: Okay! `:use_school` doesn't have any type: it may be a string, a boolean…